# Convert data frame into set using python

Tags: python, pandas, set

I have multiple data frames and need to convert that into sets. I have converted that for single data frame but now need to do it in loop so if I get any no of data frame then will get converted into set using loop. Need individual set for individual data frame. I have used

```
all_elems = list(set().union(*set_names))
```

but not works as per my requirement. I want to convert these data frame into set to plot that union set values for visualization.

[image]
[image]

Comment: if possible then please share the dataframe

Comment: Can you please explain why do you need to convert a dataframe to a set? And what structure do you expect for the resulting set? Dataframe is a 2D data structure, but set can not have a nested set so you can say its 1D structure

Comment: I have edited my question with data frame. For upset plot I need my output in set

Comment: @varshapatil, so you just want the values in `INSTANCE_ID` column to be converted to a set?

Comment: Yes. I have other columns in csv files but need to work with only INSTANCE_ID so created data frame with that column only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to convert the values in the columns to set, you can use `series.agg` and pass `set` as the aggregate:

```py
file1 = df['INSTANCE_ID'].agg(set)
```

It will get you the values in the column as a set. You can do the same for all the dataframes

#### SAMPLE RUN

```py
>>> df =  pd.DataFrame({'INSTANCE_ID': [random.randint(0,3) for _ in range(5)]})
>>> df
   INSTANCE_ID
0            0
1            1
2            0
3            1
4            0

>>> df['INSTANCE_ID'].agg(set)
{0, 1}
```

Since you want the union of all the sets, better option will be just to concatenate all the dataframe column values, then create the set:

```py
result = pd.concat([df1['INSTANCE_ID'], df2['INSTANCE_ID'], ...., dfn['INSTANCE_ID']]).agg(set)
```

Comment: I need to do that in loop. My data frame name is Dataframe name : CAM-intersect/Book2.csv. I want one loop from that will convert all data frame into set. Not single data frame.